# Performance impact of initializing array in PHP-which method is faster

Tags: php, arrays, performance

Which of the following two is faster? Only difference being an explicit `array()` initialization.

```
$fields['a'] = 1;
$fields['b'] = 2;
```

vs.

```
$fields = array();
$fields['a'] = 1;
$fields['b'] = 2;
```

Comment: Is this the slowest part of your code?

Comment: It does not make sense if you don't initialize it. Make codes logical.

Answer (score 6):

Instead of worrying about performance, you should be writing sensible, readable code. This is much better:

```
$fields = array();
$fields['a'] = 1;
$fields['b'] = 2;
```

compared to this:

```
$fields['a'] = 1;
$fields['b'] = 2;
```

You might save few fractions of a second of a machine; but you will definitely waste valuable time of the person who reads your code. He/she will will have to scroll through your code to locate where `$fields` is initialized and if it already contains some values.

Comment: When I have situations like this I prefer: `$fields = array('a' => 1, 'b' => 2);`. It saves keystrokes and is easy to understand, IMO.

Answer (score 2):

**Caution:** These numbers vary from hardware to hardware

`0.0000109672546386720` seconds without array();

**VS**

`0.0000090599060058594` seconds with array(); (faster!)

But better with array(); Seems more logical.

Comment: @MarkBaker i did average of 100 Tests

Answer (score 2):

Micro Benchmark does not make sense just `focus on more readable code` but for education purpose this is the fastest

```
$array = array('a' => 1,'b' => 2); // fastest PHP 5.4
$array = ['a' => 1,'b' => 2]; // fastest PHP 5.5
```

[See Benchmark](http://codepad.viper-7.com/1zifCR)